# Laravel migration timestamp - Separate data and time

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my migration I have a timestamp which gets the current data and time when a row is posted.

Is it possible to get just the time or just the date from this, or would I have to use a separate timestamp for each?

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Comment: Just store it how it is by default and format it how you need it, Laravel comes with Carbon for date time stuff, https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ Create a Carbon object from your timestamp and use the in built functions to split out what you need.

Comment: To be precise `created_at->format('H:i:s');` Delete the post after you figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DaveCarruthers recommended, use the default `timestamps()` columns.

Then separate date and time when you need to:

```php
$model->created_at->toDateString();
$model->created_at->toTimeString();
```